# Give url specified image and name when saving in Django

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library

I need the name of an image that is saved according to the value of an attribute of my model.

For example, if a field is called `NameEvent`, I have a value that is `Django-Event`, then the filename of the image is saved as `Django-event.jpg`.

```
from django.db import models
from uuid import uuid4
from datetime import date
import os

class Post(models.Model):

    def _generar_ruta_imagen(instance, filename):
        # El primer paso es extraer la extension de la imagen del
        # archivo original
        extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1][1:]

        # Generamos la ruta relativa a MEDIA_ROOT donde almacenar
        # el archivo, usando la fecha actual (año/mes)
        ruta = os.path.join('Imagenes', date.today().strftime("%Y/%m"))

        # Generamos el nombre del archivo con un identificador
        # aleatorio, y la extension del archivo original.
        nombre_archivo = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, extension)

        # Devolvermos la ruta completa
        return os.path.join(ruta, nombre_archivo)

    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to=_generar_ruta_imagen)

    text = models.TextField(max_lenght=1000)
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? First of all, the code you posted gives the filename as `some_uuid.extension`, not `some_attribute_value.extension`. Is the question how to name the file pre-save, or how to retrieve it once saved (in which case the snippet doesn't correspond to what you say should happen)?

Comment: Also, note that `_generar_ruta_imagen` won't work as it is. You'll have to take it out of the class or decorate it with `@staticmethod`. This way Python expects it to be a bound method, so will try to pass the class instance as the first argument, so you'll get a mismatch in number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageField` has a method `get_filename`, you would need to call it like this:

```
post.imagen.get_filename(filename) # To retrieve it pre-save
```

Where `filename` is the same name you provide on the field instantiation

You could also do something like this once the object has been saved:

```
post.imagen.name # To retrieve it post-save
```